# Disabling the editing of the order shipping details by admin in WooCommerce backend

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, orders

We use the `wc_order_is_editable` hook to disable the editing of the order items on the backend for some order statuses.

```php
add_filter( 'wc_order_is_editable', 'wc_make_orders_editable', 10, 2 );
function wc_make_orders_editable( $is_editable, $order ) {
    if ( $order->get_status() == 'completed' ) {
        $is_editable = false;
    }

    return $is_editable;
}
```

---

But i wanted to disable the ability to change the shipping details (Name, Address, etc.) as well.

The logic is that if an order isn't sent already i let our staff change the order items and the shipping info but once the order is sent i want to disable it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not immediately a filter to adjust this, so you could use some `jQuery`, to hide the edit icon.

- Only on order edit page
- Checks for user role, administrator
- Based on one or more order statuses

---

**Important:** Because no direct distinction is made between "billing details" and "shipping details" contains the `H3` selector a part of the title

```js
$( "h3:contains('Shipping') .edit_address" );
```

Where 'shipping' may need to be replaced by the title in the language that you use.

- [:contains() Selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

---

So you get:

```php
function action_admin_footer () {
    global $pagenow;
    
    // Only on order edit page
    if ( $pagenow != 'post.php' || get_post_type( $_GET['post'] ) != 'shop_order' ) return;
    
    // Get current user
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    // Safe usage
    if ( ! ( $user instanceof WP_User ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // In array, administrator role
    if ( in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) {
        // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
        $order = wc_get_order( get_the_id() );
        
        // Is a WC_Order
        if ( is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) {
            // Get order status
            $order_status = $order->get_status();
            
            // Status in array
            if ( in_array( $order_status, array( 'pending', 'on-hold', 'processing' ) ) ) {
                ?>
                <script>
                jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
                    // IMPORTANT: edit H3 tag contains 'Shipping' if necessary
                    $( "h3:contains('Shipping') .edit_address" ).hide();
                });
                </script>
                <?php
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'action_admin_footer', 10, 0 );
```

Comment: Thanks @7uc1f3r great answer. Just out of curiosity, do you know if this approach of using jquery is the one used for disabling the editing of the order items? thanks

Comment: The display of the edit icon (order items) is determined by an if condition via php code `if ( $order->is_editable() )`, via the `wc_order_is_editable` filter you can determine whether this is true or false. The edit icon for the shipping details is not included in such an if condition, hence this is not editable via the filter hook and a solution like jQuery must be used